# Error while importing Framer Web component to Next js

Tags: next.js, import, framer-motion, framerjs

[I keep getting this error while I try to import some framer web comonents to my next js project
Is there some work around???
have been trying to fix this for hours now. Thanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZyqU.png)

I was trying to import a smart componrnt from framer web to my next js project using url imports but some components have been throwing this error I have o clue why... been trying to fix this for hours.. Thanks